# ObjectDataSource and LINQ technicality

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, objectdatasource

I've a little question on LINQ.

I have a collection of categories (about 100). Some of them are children of another category. This is an `IList` of this type:

```
 public Guid TempID { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }
 public bool Published { get; set; }
 public int CategoryLevel { get; set; }
 public int CategoryOrder { get; set; }
 public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> RefParent { get; set; }
 public bool GotChildren { get; set; }
```

What is the best approach if I want to represent this type in a `DataList` (potentially a `DataList` of `DataList`, of `DataList`, etc) using **ASP.net**. Another technicality is that the number of children is not static. We presently have 3 depth but it can easly have 5.

Must say that I can't change where and how data are return because it's how it comes from an external API. What I've to do, it's simply showing them.

Thank you, and feel free to ask me more details. I'm from quebec and usualy talk french so maybe me english is not very good.

**Edit**
Must tell that I know how to databind the DataList. My problem is realy how can I DataBind a datalist of datalist (and don't know the depth) to a Simple dimension list that contains all level. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for posterity's sake...
`List<Category> categories` should be fine. Properties are exposed via something like :

```
categories[0].TempID
```

You can run LINQ against the collection:

```
var catIDs = from cat in categories
             where cat.ID.HasValue == true
             select cat;
```

**UPDATE_3:**

Okay, I understand now - you receive an object that looks like:

```
 public Guid TempID { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }
 public bool Published { get; set; }
 public int CategoryLevel { get; set; }
 public int CategoryOrder { get; set; }
 public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> RefParent { get; set; }
 public bool GotChildren { get; set; }
```

...and you need to be able to add collections of child categories?

If you cannot inherit the class, I would consume the object by:

```
class MyCategory
{
    // add fields for respective Category properties
    // or just the following
    Category category;
    List<Category> subCategories;

    MyCategory (Category category)
    {
        this.category = category;

        if (this.category.GotChildren)
        {
            // query TempIDs, Level, etc. from collection of Categories
            // and assign to subCategories collection
        }
    }

    // add property getters/setters as needed
    public List<Category> SubCategories
    { get { return subCategories; } }
}
```

...externally, call:

```
bool TryGetSubCategories (MyCategory myCategory, out DataList myDataList)
{
    if (myCategory.GotChildren)
    {myDataList.DataSource = myCategory.SubCategories;}

    return myCategory.GotChildren;
}
```

Updated the method to work in similar fashion to Dictionary.TryGetValue();

**UPDATE_2:**

You will need to add a collection (`ICollection`, `List<T>`, etc.) property to your type:

```
 public Guid TempID { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }
 public bool Published { get; set; }
 public int CategoryLevel { get; set; }
 public int CategoryOrder { get; set; }
 public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> RefParent { get; set; }
 public bool GotChildren { get; set; }
 public List<Categories> SubCategories {get; set;} // add this
```

This will add unlimited depth. I don't see why couldn't use the DataList as your SubItems data type.

**UPDATE:**

After looking at the DataList class more carefully, you must use an `ICollection` as the DataSource. MSDN shows that `List<T>` inherits from `ICollection` & `ICollection<T>`. `IList` inherits from `ICollection`; while `IList<T>` inherits from `ICollection<T>`.

MSDN also has [a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.items.aspx).

Comment: Basicaly, I know how to databind a Datalist to an ObjectDataSource. What I'm not confortable with is how to databind my DataList, which can have many children datalist, to a single List that contains all level on the first dimension. Don't know if I tell it correctly...

Comment: And, about your response, you must bind the datalist on every postback otherwize it don't shows on postbacks

Comment: @Simon: the postback portion is copied directly from MSDN - this is the sample they provide. How do you know how deep your child objects will go?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know the deep! It can change every weeks.

Comment: My IList<Categories> is having all the categories of all `CategoryLevel` in it. But I need to have a DataList for Level 1. Into this DataList1, DataListItems have another DataList for Level 2 that have `RefParent` == ((Category)DataListItem.DataItem).ID. But how I can do this when I'm only having 1 IList<Categories> as source.

Comment: @Simon: can you not modify your sample object?

Comment: My sample object is the result of an external API. So no, I can't modify it. Hehe, I think you just understand what is my problem right? ;o)

Comment: @Simon: no doubt you will have to build your own collection type. Consume the object by passing in as parameter to your own object with the added collection property.

Comment: Just to there it's ok. It's all things I know how to do. But now, how do you bind a datalist of datalist according to this without forgeting that you don't know the depth!? This is where I'm stuck!

Comment: Simon, are you speaking about Silverlight/WPF data binding?